Framework for real time animation of industrial physics simulation
Sorry for the long post, but some context is needed to state the question. Also keep in mind that all of the current people on the team are mechanical engineers by profession and not software developers, so I hope this doesn't comes across as too uninformed.
I am working on a potential start-up in an industrial field (oil drilling). The idea involves around real time simulation of an industrial process. The code for simulation is written in C++ for Linux and is well on its way. We are now looking for a framework for real-time animation of the output data.
The typical way that large scale non real-time HPC simulations are visualized is that  output data is written to output files or an output database at regular time intervals and these files are post-processed by a separate program afterwards. This is how we are currently writing output, but this approach will be not be performant enough for real time rendering. Keep in mind that the simulation created here is indented to run in real time and we also want to be able to render it in real time. I guess this makes the application have certain commonalities with video games. However, there are still major differences. My impression is that for most video games, the major workload is the visualization itself, not the game logic/physics.
In our application the physics simulation is very demanding, but there isn't that much output to visualize. Therefore I think we could in principle opt for a development friendly, but less performant framework for the visualization. We might also want to add GUI elements later.
My request boils down to recommendations on frameworks/architecture to enable this animation. One of the major decisions needed to be made is whether we should opt for something C++ based for the animation or use a different language/framework. I have already looked at some "frameworks", but I'm not sure which of these could be most suitable. Some frameworks I'm aware of include:

OpenGL (using C++)
PyOpenGL
Three.js
P5.js
VTK (using C++. Commonly used to postprocess numerical simulation data, not sure if it's suitable for real time though.)

My main concern if we choose something non C++ based (like Three.js for instance), is how we will efficiently communicate data from the C++ simulator side to the visualization. If we need lots of additional boilerplate code to transfer data, the advantages of using a simpler visualization framework might be not be worth it.
On the other hand, if we choose something C++ based (like OpenGL) I guess we could make more of a "monolithic" application in C++ (like a game). However, my impression here is if we base everything on C++ this might making GUI elements etc. harder than necessary and it might also be a bit overkill since the visualization itself won't be that demanding. We also might want to keep options like web-based solutions etc. open, so ideally it should be possible to accomplish this with the chosen framework.
We intent to hire someone dedicated to work on the visualization, but it would be nice to know more about exactly what we need in advance.
So what kind of frameworks could be recommended, and should we opt for a monolithic C++ based approach or a more decoupled approach using a different language? And in the latter case, how could data efficiently be transferred from the simulation to the visualization?
Or are all of the mentioned alternatives bad and are we better of handling it in an alternative way?
Sorry if this questions comes across as very general, or if it should have been posted on "Software Engineering" instead.
